# Ending ruby program if a given condition is met

Tags: ruby, break, ruby-1.9

Basically, I am just trying to stop the program from running the rest of the lines if a certain condition is met.

```
unless raw_information.first
  puts "No results were returned for that query"
  break
end
```

However, before the program even runs I get this error:

> Invalid break
>   compile error (SyntaxError)

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
abort("No results were returned for that query") unless condition
```

or

```
unless condition
  abort("No results were returned for that query")
end
```